# How to print the and update the scoreboard on the same line here?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iomanip>

int Human_Roll() {

int num1;

srand(time(0));

num1 = (1 + rand() % 6);

return num1;
}

int Human_Roll_2() {

int num2;

num2 = (1 + rand() % 6);

return num2;
}


int Computer_Roll() {

int num3;

num3 = (1 + rand() % 6);

return num3;


}

int Coumputer_Roll_2() {

int num4;

num4 = (1 + rand() % 6);

return num4;
}

int main() {

int counter1 = 0, counter2 = 0;
char start;



for (int i = 1; i <= 150; i++) {

    std::cin >> start;

    int x1{ Human_Roll() };
    int x2{ Human_Roll_2() };


    int y1{ Computer_Roll() };
    int y2{ Coumputer_Roll_2() };

    int x;
    int y;
    x = x1 + x2;

    y = y1 + y2;

    std::cout << "\nYou:          " << x1 << " + " << x2 << " = "  << x << "\n\n";

    std::cout << "Computer:       " << y1 << " + " << y2 << " = " << y << "\n";

    if (x > y) {
        std::cout << "\nYou win." << "\n";
        ++counter1;
    }

    if (y > x) {
        std::cout << "\nYou lose. " << "\n";
        ++counter2;
    }

    if (x == y) {
        std::cout << "\nDraw. " << "\n";
        counter1 += 0;
        counter2 += 0;
    }

    std::cout << "               Scoreboard: " << counter1 << " - "  << counter2 << "\n";

    if (counter1 == 7) {
        std::cout << "\n\n      Victory!     " << "\n";
        break;
    }

    if (counter2 == 7) {
        std::cout << "\n\n      Loss!     " << "\n";
        break;
    }


}
```

This is a supposed to be a dice game that calculates the sum of two randomly generated sides of the 6 sided dices. It does it two times and compares the sums to pick the winner with the bigger sum, and it should print out the scoreline every time the the winner is declared. My question is, how can I make the scoreline be updated on the same line as the game continues and not print "scoreboard x - y " every time the round is finished?

Comment: Which Operating System? C++ doesn't have a way of cursor positioning, other than going to the next line or character. You'll need to use a system-dependant library

Answer (score 0):

As @enhzflep said this will end up being more than complicated solution for the system dependent code.

However the easy and quick solution is for visually having the same line being updated is to create many empty lines for every for loop iteration.

```
for (int n = 0; n < 50; n++)
    {
        std::cout << "\n";
    }
```

As i said earlier this is the best c++ could do when there is no system information available. Using the standard commands.

updated for loop would look like

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 150; i++) {


        int x1{ Human_Roll() };
        int x2{ Human_Roll_2() };


        int y1{ Computer_Roll() };
        int y2{ Coumputer_Roll_2() };

        int x;
        int y;
        x = x1 + x2;

        y = y1 + y2;
        std::cout << " ----- Game " << i << " -----";
        std::cout << "\nYou:          " << x1 << " + " << x2 << " = "  << x << "\n";
        std::cout << "Computer:       " << y1 << " + " << y2 << " = " << y << "\n";
        if (x > y) {
            std::cout << "\nYou win." << "\n";
            ++counter1;
        }
        if (y > x) {
            std::cout << "\nYou lose. " << "\n";
            ++counter2;
        }
        if (x == y) {
            std::cout << "\nDraw. " << "\n";
            counter1 += 0;
            counter2 += 0;
        }
        std::cout << "---------------------------------------------"
        std::cout << "Scoreboard: " << counter1 << " - "  << counter2 << "\n";

        if (counter1 == 7) {
            std::cout << "\n\n      Victory!     " << "\n";
            break;
        }

        if (counter2 == 7) {
            std::cout << "\n\n      Loss!     " << "\n";
            break;
        }

        for (int n = 0; n < 50; n++)
        {
              std::cout << "\n";
        }
}
```

There are other ways to do it such as

- Sysetm call to clear the terminal

  > but this method not safe [why](http://www.cplusplus.com/articles/j3wTURfi/)
- The standard way to print end lines
- Using the curser library `#include <curses.h>`

  > Advantage it is a cross-platform but can not be mixed with standard I/O

Answer (score 0):

Hi from what I' m understanding you want o clear the console like this `std::cout << "\033[2J\033[1;1H";` so when you roll the dices again the code comes in the same place but before you do this you need to stop the console make it wait for input and say something like "Press enter to play again" then the console clears and the next game comes in the same place or you can use something like `Sleep(milliseconds);` before cleaning.

Hope this is what you looking for.